# CS0029 при записи элемента в строку C#

Tags: c#, массивы

Когда я присваивал строке(string) элемент из массива символов компилятор пишет ошибку CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'.

Код:

```
char[] Arr = new char[3];
string Str = Arr[0] + Arr[1] + Arr[2];   // Тут компилятор выдает ошибку
```

Как возникает такая ошибка - не понимаю, может [IDE](https://ide.goorm.io/) глючная.

Comment: Просто оставлю это здесь `string Str = new string(Arr)`

Comment: @aepot на самом деле мне нужно помещать в строку не весь массив, а только часть.

Comment: Ну вы этот нюанс только что рассекретили, но и это не проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string Str = Arr[0].ToString() + ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Так происходит потому, что тип char, как бы не казалось на первый взгляд,  является не строкой, а кодом (int) символа UTF-16.
Если ближе к Вашей теме, то можно использовать [интерполяцию строк](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation), т.к. это является "синтаксическим сахаром", то для каждого char метод ToString будет вызван автоматически:

```cs
char[] arr = new char[3];
string str = $"{arr[0]}{arr[1]}{arr[2]}";
```

Либо, как уже указал [Igor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176262/igor), использовать [перегруженный конструктор String](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_String__ctor_System_Char___), передав в него либо весь массив, либо какой-либо его диапазон:

```cs
char[] arr = new char[3];
string str = new string(arr);
```